# PHP in_array() method tells me I'm passing a null value while it's not, hint?

Tags: php, arrays, class, components

I'm implementing a PHP (5.4.4) class for including class definitions (in a dynamic fashion) for HTML rendering, so if I have a form with two buttons, four text inputs and a checkbox, I just include the .php files corresponding to a form, a textbox and a button, and not anything else (each HTML object is represented with a class).

But I have a problem... I created a class called ComponentManager for managing the loading process, with this code:

```
    class ComponentManager {
    // component manager properties
    protected $components;

    // constructor for this object
    public function __construct() {
        if (!empty($_SESSION['components'])) {
            $this->components = explode(" ", $_SESSION['components']);
        } else {
            $this->components = null;
        }
    }

    // destructor for this object
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->components = null;
    }

    // getter for this object
    public function __get($property) {
        if ($property === "components") {
            return $this->components;
        }
    }

    // addComponents - add components to the current components list
    public function addComponents($components) {
        if (!empty($components)) {
            $list = explode(" ", $components);

            $count = sizeof($list);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                if (!in_array($list[$i], $this->components)) {
                    $this->components[] = $list[$i];
                    $component = null;
```

The problem is I seem to be failing with the in_array() function and I don't know why... I mean, I've used it a lot of times in the past for different things but keeps telling me this:

> **Warning**: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in **D:\apache\htdocs\webapps\skeleton\assets\scripts\manager.php** on line **34**

I pass $components in my test code as a whitespace-separated list, like this:

```
$page->addComponents("form checkbox textbox button range number");
```

My intention is to specify: if the component list is **not empty**, give me an array with the entered components, and for each one of the components, insert it **if and only if** it's not already present in the components array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$this->components` is not an array. I believe it is because in your constructor, `$this->components` is being defined as null.

Comment: `$_SESSION['components']` is probably empty, have you checked that? (and, did you have a proper `session_start` on this page? Also, I would initialize it in `__construct()` with `array()`, not with `null`. I lie, I would actually _declare_ `var $components=array();`, and not bother setting it to anything else if the session var is empty.

Comment: Just a note: Using the magic methods `__get()` and set are very slow. Especially if you are only using them to make `$this->components` read only from outside the scope of the class. IMHO, you should just be using an accessor function.

Comment: I can confirm what PhpMyCoder says about the slowness of `__get()`'s.

Comment: You set `$this->components = null;` to `null` if `$_SESSION['components']` is empty. How about setting it to `array()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, your constructor initiates `$this->components` to `null` and then you are trying to access that through `addComponents()`.

You probably meant to initiate it to `$this->components = array();` so the list starts as an empty array, thus allowing you to use `in_array()` on it?

Comment: Pfffff one hour looking at the code and it was all reduced to initiating my property to `$this->components = [];`. Thank you very much for the hint! :)